# docker-compose replace argument with "0"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, arguments

I'm currently using a docker-compose file as such

```
myservice:
    image: ${REGISTRY}:5000/myservice
    build:
        context: myservice/
        args:
            - "ENVIRONMENT=${environment}"
            - enablecron=0
```

The environment variable `environment` is equal to `preprod`.
I'm using this dockerfile Dockerfile:

```
FROM basicssh
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT
ARG enablecron
ENV enablecron $enablecron

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && apt-get -y install lsb-release apt-transport-https ca-certificates wget
RUN wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
RUN echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && apt-get install -y php7.4 php7.4-mbstring php7.4-fpm php7.4-mysql php7.4-memcached php7.4-memcache php7.4-xml php7.4-redis gpg nginx

# Adding cron
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron
RUN echo "0 0 * * 1 php /var/www/htdocs/cron/index.php run >> /var/log/nginx/cron.log 2>&1" > /tmp/crontab
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "if [[ x$enablecron == x1 ]]; then cat /tmp/crontab | crontab -; else echo Not adding cron; fi"]

RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
RUN mkdir /run/php
ADD ./scripts/start2.sh /start2.sh
ADD ./config/config.${ENVIRONMENT}.xml /var/www/config.xml
ADD ./config/*.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

CMD ["/bin/bash", "/start2.sh"]
EXPOSE 80
```

At line `ADD ./config/config.${ENVIRONMENT}.xml /var/www/config.xml`, most of the time I have a crash saying `* Status: ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder932292957/config/config.0.xml: no such file or directory, Code: 1`

This `environment` variable is NOT equal to 0. Sometime it will also work (with the correct environment value) without any change.

I'm using docker-compose 2.1.0 and docker 20.10.10 (server version 19.03.14).

Comment: if you add a `RUN echo "$ENVIRONMENT $enablecron"` statement right after assigning ENVs, what will you see in the build log, do you see the ENVIRONMENT var is set to 0?

Comment: Yes, when it crashes, it shows 0 instead of the real env/arg.

Comment: Here is a crazy and terrifying though, do you think there could be a race condition with the variable(a) where you set them?

Comment: How do you run your docker-compose file, what if you set the variable in the .env file or in regular file with —env-file?

Comment: The variable is in the current environment, with `export environment=production` in bash

Comment: Have you tried changing the variable name, just out of curiosity…

Comment: Yeah, it used to be lowercased an I've uppercased it.